# RegEx issue - No delimiter

Tags: regex

I have the next log string :

```
E.....@..@:......F....2...148.277.90.903 - - [15/Nov/2015:16:10:00] "GET
```

How is it possible to separate the IP address (note that it is no have delimiter)

I tried unsuccessfully the next regex:

```
(\S+)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - - \[(.*)] \(.*)
```

Comment: `148.277.90.903` isn't valid IP address

Comment: It's indeed not a valid IP, but it does not matter for answering the question.

Comment: I'm no expert, but for isolating the ip-address `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})` should work (at least for your particular string) - there's also probably better/prettier options, but it's the first thing that came to my mind

Comment: Your `(\S+)` "eats up" the first digit(s) of your IP address because `+` is greedy. If your were more specific here e.g. `(\D+)` it might help. And you should escape the dots in your IP address pattern because the dot alone matches every character. Escaping it to `\.` matches only a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and don't forget to escape the dots:

```
\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b
```

Note that this doesn't do any error checking. It will simply look for four integers separated by dots.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

...that is, one to three digits separated by literal periods.  Or if you want to be minimalist and mysterious:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

See https://regex101.com/r/dW3mT1/1 (which is an awesome tool that everyone should be using).